# How to create bootable Windows 8 iso image in Linux?

Tags: windows, iso, bootable, mkisofs

I have to insert the `Autounattend.xml` file into a Windows 8 iso image to make the iso install automatically. My system need to run on Linux and only could use Linux shell command, so ISO tools on Winodws such as UltraISO can not be used.

I have tried several methods, but all the created iso could not be booted, just printed

```
CDBOOT: Cannot boot from CD - Code: 5
```

A. The first method I tried is: [tuto](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/RHEL/Installation/Kickstart/modifing_iso_image_to_include_kickstart_file.shtml)

1. Mount iso to a folder
2. Copy the mounted iso content into a new folder
3. Add my files into the new folder
4. Use `mkisofs` command to create a new iso image

   ```
   mkisofs -o windows2008_new.iso -b boot/etfsboot.com -no-emul-boot   -boot-load-size 8 -boot-info-table  -V -J -l -D -N -UDF  -relaxed-filenames -V "WINSP"
   ```

B. The second method I tried:

MS cmd tool named "oscdimg" on Windows to create new Windows iso, it works. So I copy the oscdimg into Linux and use Wine to run it, it can not be run normally.

Does any one know how to make bootable Windows iso image in Linux using pure shell command?

Comment: `wine` is not for 'running' iso images. Try `qemu-kvm`, `xen` or `virtualbox`

Comment: the 'oscdimg' is a cmd tool from Microsoft, runing in windows, but can not run in linux use wine(wine oscdimg).    https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: take a look at this blog: https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-a-windows-7-install-iso/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I resolve the problem finally.          In the blog, use 'dd' method to get the boot.img, and use this boot.img as the boot file to create new image. Actually, the boot.img is same as the file in boot/etfsboot.com file in the iso. So, both two command below could create correct window bootable iso.  "mkisofs -o ../windows2008_test.iso -b boot.img  -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -iso-level 2 -udf -J -l -D -N -relaxed-filenames ." and "mkisofs -o ../windows2008_hw.iso -b boot/etfsboot.img  -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -iso-level 2 -udf -J -l -D -N -relaxed-filenames ."

Comment: @Serge. It is the copy file error that make my created iso boot failed. While read your blog, I make a diff among the 'boot.img' from 'dd', the raw 'etfsboot.com' file in the iso mount point and the same file copy into a directory to make iso. I find the 'boot.img' is same with the raw 'etfsboot.com', but not same with the copied  one on the filesystem. I copy all the iso file again and make a new iso, it works! There mybe some error occur while copy iso content to filesystem. Thanks for your inspiration!

Comment: Not at all. BTW, it's not my blog ;)

Comment: @user170602 Please, summarise your method here  too because I cannot get the method work which is discussed in the thread. Note I am trying to implement it for Windows 10 iso.

Comment: When using `mkisofs`, there is always -udf parameter. But when I remove it from the command, the generated iso file is not bootable. Do you know the reason? `mkisofs -o ../windows10.iso -betfsboot.com -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -iso-level 2 -l -D -N -V "WINSP" .`

Answer (score 4):

I managed to successfully use `genisoimage` ([a debian fork of mkisofs](https://wiki.debian.org/genisoimage)).

Method:

1. loopback mount the iso

   ```
   mount -o loop <image>.iso /mnt/iso
   ```
2. copy to secondary folder for r/w access

   ```
   cp -R /mnt/iso/ /mnt/iso2
   ```
3. make changes
4. ```
   genisoimage -b <relative boot-img path> -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -iso-level 2 -udf -joliet -D -N -relaxed-filenames -o <new-image>.iso /mnt/iso2.`
   ```

Comment: `genisoimage` is not a fork from `mkisofs`, since a fork would require active development and own features. `genisoimage` however just added plenty of bugs and is not recommended. The command line you propose works perfectly with the original software and even avoids to cause structural defects in the resulting filesystem image. While `genisoimage` is still in the state from 2004, `mkisofs` nearly doubled it's features.

Comment: any explanation what is the `relative boot-img path` ?

Comment: the rel boot-img path is `boot\etfsboot.com` also add `-boot-load-seg 0x07C0` option. sadly the resulting iso does not work with uefi (like qemu ovmf)

Answer (score 1):

Proposed method for Windows 7 but it does not work with Windows 10 iso file

```
# https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-a-windows-7-install-iso/
$ dd if=../en_windows_10_x64_dvd.iso \
    of=boot.img bs=2048 count=8 skip=734

$ mkisofs -o ../new-win.iso -b boot.img -no-emul-boot -c BOOT.CAT \
    -iso-level 2 -udf \
    -J -l -D -N -joliet-long -relaxed-filenames .
```

Output unsuccessful in the first step

```
dd if=/home/masi/Downloads/en_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1511_x64_dvd.iso of=/home/masi/Downloads/boot.img bs=2048 count=8 skip=734
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
16384 bytes (16 kB) copied, 0.000392973 s, 41.7 MB/s
```

Please, let me know if you find any newer method for the task.

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Targeting hardware: Asus PC

Comment: I extended this wiki answer to a new thread here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312488/16920 because the case is different in Windows 10 at least in parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing but with `ei.cfg`; here's how I did it:

First create a mountpoint:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/image
```

Mount the official Windows image to `/mnt/image`:

```
sudo mount -o loop Win10_2004_English_x64.iso /mnt/image
```

Create a separate directory `/tmp/bootableWin` for your modifications, respecting the ISO folder structure, as you can't edit the loop mount.

In my case:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/bootableWin/sources
sudo tee /tmp/bootableWin/sources/ei.cfg <<EOF
[Channel]
Retail
EOF
```

And finally package it:

```
mkisofs \
    -iso-level 4 \
    -l \
    -R \
    -UDF \
    -D \
    -b boot/etfsboot.com \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 8 \
    -hide boot.catalog \
    -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -eltorito-platform efi \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -b efi/microsoft/boot/efisys.bin \
    -o /home/username/win10-outputimage.iso \
    /mnt/image /tmp/bootableWin/
```

Now you should have both a BIOS and a UEFI bootable image with your added file in it.

Comment: I did a quick Google search yesterday, and it looked like > 75% of the resources say you should use `-udf`. Can you justify your insistence on `-UDF`?

Comment: Can you justify your requested change?
This is what I tested with, this is what I confirmed works.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, I didn’t request a change; I just questioned your choice. [As you know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/360377), two days ago, somebody suggested changing `-UDF` to `-udf`, and two high-reputation users approved that edit. What you can’t see is that I was presented with the opportunity to vote on xiota’s edit, and I abstained after my independent research showed support for both forms (but, as I said, mostly `-udf`), and as I said, I was asking why you overrode so many other voices.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (1) If you have used this successfully, it might help to mention that in your answer, ideally specifying the environment (OS and ``mkisofs`` version). (2) Have you tried `-udf`? If it works on your system, why not go along with the crowd? (3) Apparently a lot of people believe that `-UDF` is wrong. If there are systems where it doesn’t work, then your answer will be useless for people with such systems. (4) Based on the above, in order to make your answer helpful to the most people, I encourage you to (at least) add a note telling users to try `-udf` if `-UDF` doesn’t work for them.

Comment: (1) Pointless in this case as the current cdrtools version is from 3 years ago

(2) I did not try, hence why I overrode the suggested edit which had no justification attached to it.

(3-4) Good enough that it's in the comments now.