# How to Create Bootable Windows 10 image in Debian?

Tags: windows, dd, iso, bootable, mkisofs

Pseudocode but originally developed for Windows 7 iso file but applied for Windows 8 in the thread [How to create bootable Windows 8 iso image in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283446/16920) but it does not work with Windows 10 iso

```
# https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-a-windows-7-install-iso/
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312477/16920
$ dd if=../en_windows_10_x64_dvd.iso \
    of=boot.img bs=2048 count=8 skip=734

$ mkisofs -o ../new-win.iso -b boot.img -no-emul-boot -c BOOT.CAT \
    -iso-level 2 -udf \
    -J -l -D -N -joliet-long -relaxed-filenames .
```

Unsuccessful output when run on Windows 10 image

```
dd if=/home/masi/Downloads/en_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1511_x64_dvd.iso of=/home/masi/Downloads/boot.img bs=2048 count=8 skip=734
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
16384 bytes (16 kB) copied, 0.000392973 s, 41.7 MB/s
```

Some of the following fields have changed for the iso file used in `dd`

- `bs=2048`
- `count=8`
- `skip=734`

How can you study which field values you can use for Windows 10 iso?

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Related threads: [How to create bootable Windows 7 iso image in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283446/16920), [Customizing a Windows 7 install ISO](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-a-windows-7-install-iso/)
Motivation: I need Windows 10 to use Canon P-150 duplex scanner, but when I started my Windows, I got Error *0xC0000428* because Windows update has again broken things there and I use Windows otherwise so rarely; and I have no spare Windows left to make bootable media

Comment: Please check the answer I have provided here, building upon contributions from other members https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531012/how-to-modify-an-installation-iso-and-keep-it-bootable/635839#635839 (this procedure resulted in a EFI bootable win10 ISO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reliable solution which I found for the case. 
Create bootable Windows in Windows.

Comment: Fine if you don't obtain the 0x80080005 error which I did. Microsoft help completely useless for resolving the issue so I've presented my Linux Debian solution below.

Comment: The question was about doing it in Debian ... not windows. I may have found a way.
I will post as soon as I get a chance to test it

Answer (score 16):

I tried the Win7 solution described by Microsoft on a Windows machine:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

and obtained the

> 0x80080005 error

so went to Debian Stretch 9 to try to build the Windows 10 bootable USB using a e5.onthehub.com college/school ISO.

Using `dd` absolutely doesn't work for Windows 10. This only works for Linux OSes. Use:

```
dd if=my-linux-os.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

Note: Never try write to `/dev/sdX1` where `X={a,b,c or d}` and always check you are not overwriting your hard disk which is usually `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`!

For Windows 10 you can use WoeUSB but not from the apt/yum repos. These ones are obsolete, at least for Debian 9. So instead use:

```
git clone https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB.git
```

Then follow the instructions at the end of:

https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB

You must have all the prerequisites such as gparted and so forth installed first.

I also found at the end of the process that I must run woeusb with sudo. So you just use:

```
sudo woeusb --device local/of/my/windows-10-image.iso /dev/sdX
```

and hey presto it just works brilliantly. In my case my harddisk was `/dev/sda` and my USB drive was `/dev/sdb` so I wrote the ISO to `/dev/sdb` (again be careful, you don't want to overwrite your OS by accident). I then installed it on a military class MSI motherboard with 2TB hard disk attached with no fast boot options inside the BIOS and it just works. I turned on absolutely every UEFI option first to get it into the right state.

I also had problems at install time, with the system hanging forever when using a Gmail email account for login and when the internet cable was connected at the second restart of the machine (during the install process). If you have this issue, disconnect internet, restart machine, let generic account be built, login, restart with internet cable

Comment: Awesome. It  helped me

Comment: This truly works, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I had to use `--target-filesystem NTFS` like this: `sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /path/to/image.iso /dev/sd?` to avoid an error regarding file size larger than 4GB in FAT32 file system.

Comment: woeusb from github did not work for me... but I found my own solution and posted it

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to boot a UEFI-based computer, just mount the Windows ISO (take care that it is a UDF formatted ISO) and copy all files to the USB drive. As long as the drive is in FAT32 format, a UEFI computer will recognize it and it will offer the option to boot from it.

On the other hand, for a BIOS-based machine, the best option is to manually configure syslinux to chainload the Windows boot. I tried this on Windows 8, but not yet on 10. `/dev/sdf` is your USB drive.

- Format the USB to FAT32
- Make sure the USB has only one partition, and it is boot active (GParted will help with this)
- Copy all files from the ISO to the USB drive
- Install syslinux on your Linux system
- Run `syslinux -i /dev/sdf1` (the first partition on the USB drive, you can check on `lsblk`)
- Run `dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/bios/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdf bs=4M`
- Mount the USB drive and create the directory `boot/syslinux`
- Copy all `*.c32` files from `/usr/lib/syslinux/bios` to the `boot/syslinux` directory on the USB
- Create a `syslinux.cfg` text file on `boot/syslinux`, with the text

  ```
  LABEL win10
  MENU LABEL Boot Windows 10 install
  COM32 /boot/syslinux/chain.c32
  APPEND label=win7fs ntldr=/bootmgr
  ```

Edit: I'm not sure where Debian puts the syslinux files; you can find them with `find / -name "mbr.bin" 2> /dev/null`

Comment: As I wrote already, I don't know where exactly `syslinux` files are on Debian. You can find the file with `find / -name "mbr.bin" 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Any of those are ok. Debian puts the *.c32 files at `/usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/`

Comment: To copy all the *.c32 files to the `syslinux` directory on your drive. Theoretically you only need chain.c32... but I like to have all on the images; they can be useful.

Comment: How to make sure it is `UDF formatted ISO`?

Comment: This may have worked in the past but not anymore, Windows images (.wim files) in recent Windows 10 builds exceed the file size limit of FAT32.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me even with legacy/CSM boot (Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10 Version 1511 32bit; you can use genisoimage instead of mkisofs as well, mkisofs is just a symlink):

```
mkisofs \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -b boot/etfsboot.com \
  -boot-load-seg 0x07C0 \
  -boot-load-size 8 \
  -iso-level 2 \
  -udf \
  -joliet \
  -D \
  -N \
  -relaxed-filenames \
  -o win10-1511-32bit-mod1.iso \
  files/
```

(one long line, in bash with backslashes at the end for line continuation)

where `files/` is the subdirectory which contains the extracted contents of the Windows 10 ISO.

The key point seems to be the `etfsboot.com` from the `boot/` subdirectory of the Windows 10 ISO.

I can boot the burned disc with legacy/CSM without any problems.

I did only try out with the 1511 version of win10. If you try with other versions, please leave a comment.

Comment: No, `genisoimage` is a defective and dead variant of `mkisofs`. In case you only have a symlink, it is recommended to fetch a recent original that includes all the bug fixes and enhancements from the last 14 years.

Comment: @schily In Ubuntu 16.04, mkisofs is just a symlink to genisoimage. I've just tried to describe the situation at the system I've used for this as best as I could. But thank you for the information! So now we know that building the image even works with the 14 year old and buggy genisoimage used in Ubuntu 16.04. BTW, invoking `genisoimage -version` on Ubuntu 16.04 results in `genisoimage 1.1.11 (Linux)`

Comment: 14 years ago, there have been many small bugs in the resulting filesystem image. Whether you notice them depends on what you do. Important: genisoimage has absoutely no UTF-8 support. This may be important unless you only use filenames with 7 bit ASCII. If you compare genisoimage with xorriso, genisoimage may be a win since it implements rudimentary UDF support. The new mkisofs on the other side supports user/group, permissions, symlinks, device files hardlinks  and even chinese characters in filenames and better timestamps. Decide whether you are OK with a draft or like a mature program.

Comment: this works, but not with uefi (like qemu ovmf)

Answer (score 4):

FAT32 is just working for a hard to find 2018 MS-image, and exfat is hassle. After trying a lot of complex how to's that did not work, this 2 step solution succeeded:

1. Make an ntfs-partion on the USB device.
2. Execute

   ```
   woeusb --partition Win10_1909_Norwegian_x64.iso /dev/sdX1
   ```

To get `woeusb` working, I installed woeusb and grub2. Grub2 is a workaround for this:

```
grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify `--target` or `--directory`.
```

I think Woeusb should be rewritten to find correct directory. My system had the file `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh` from the `grub2-efi` package.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

This approach works fine for @TroyFolger. But I couldn't boot with the USB for some reason. Maybe my laptop's BIOS settings are messed up. Restoring BIOS to factory defaults didn't help.

#### <strike>Update</strike>

<strike>This approach did *not* work. BIOS detects the USB device as bootable, but when selecting the USB on boot menu, a blank screen is displayed before jumping to BIOS options again.</strike>

#### Approach

Combining [this post](https://linuxhint.com/create_windows_10_installer_usb_linux/) and [that one](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/), I tried this approach, replace `/dev/sd?` with your device node:

0. Optional: run `sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd? conv=fdatasync status=progress` command to clean up the USB device
1. Run `sudo cfdisk /dev/sd?` command and create a partition of `b W95 FAT 32` type. Make it ***bootable*** i.e. it should be tagged with attribute 80
2. Run `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sd?1` command to create a NTFS filesystem for the single partition created in last step. If you want it to be faster, use it with `-Q` option
3. Note: First I tried creating FAT32 filesystem, but ran into errors, due to FAT32 inability to handle files larger than 4 GB!
4. Run `sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/Win10_*.iso of=/dev/sd?1 conv=fdatasync status=progress` command to transfer content to the partition you just created. I mean the created partition on the bootable USB device.
5. Run `sudo sync` command, just in case

#### Note

At some point, my 30GB USB device stopped working. It looked like broken! However, after letting it cool down, and zeroing out all the data inside it with commands like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd?`, it worked again =)

Comment: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can create a Windows installer in a USB drive, and it works in Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: @sudodus I wish you had told me sooner. I'm almost done with the steps of [@EamonnKenny approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461478/158683), I'm going to do the final test to see if it works!

Comment: Good luck with your detailed description :-)

Comment: @sudodus I [posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598767/158683) the approach which worked fine :)

Comment: when you show the command for using `dd` to write the iso file ... you don't indicate the partition you just created, you show `/dev/sdc` as the target. Did you instead mean `/dev/sd?1` ??

Comment: I followed your steps and wrote the ISO to the created partition ... and it worked. Thank  you.

Comment: @TroyFolger I added your suggested fix to the approach steps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Update

The next generation of WoeUSB might work for you: https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng

---

## Approach

Following [@EamonnKenny approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461478/158683), I could finally boot into the Windows 10 USB:

[image: Windows 10 USB finally boots!]

I tried on an openSUSE machine, but ran into some errors. Finally tried on an **Ubuntu** machine and it worked. Here are all the commands which I ran:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB.git
$ cd WoeUSB/
$ ./setup-development-environment.bash 
$ sudo apt-get install devscripts equivs gdebi-core
$ mk-build-deps 
$ sudo gdebi woeusb-build-deps_3.3.1-1-g7171bff_all.deb
$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b
$ sudo gdebi ../woeusb_3.3.1-1-g7171bff_i386.deb
$ sudo umount /dev/sd?
$ sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /path/to/Win10_2004_English_x64.iso /dev/sd?
$ sudo eject /dev/sd?
```

#### Note

`--target-filesystem NTFS` options of `woeusb` was necessary due to:

> > ... source image has exceed the FAT32 Filesystem 4GiB Single File Size Limitation ...

Answer (score 0):

I followed @user645644 approach up to bullet point 3

There was one error message during the copying process, install.wim in the sources folder is 5.3 GB which is too large for fat32.

I skipped that error message and there were no further errors.
I looked at the woeusb source code, and split a copy of the original install.wim into two install.swm files, install.swm and install2.swm   using `wimsplit install.wim install.swm 4095`

wimsplit is from the wimlib.utils package on Fedora

I then deleted the faulty copy of install.wim and replaced it with the 2 install.swm files

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with doing it from Linux generally:

1. The official Microsoft ISO image is not a true dual mode (USB/CD)
   bootable ISO image, so you can't simply dd it to a USB stick.
2. The Windows 10 `sources/install.wim` is larger than the FAT32
   filesystem allows, so you can't just copy the contents of the ISO
   image into a FAT32 formatted USB stick

There is, however, a Linux workaround – just like the Windows `dism` tool,
there is a Linux alternative: `wimlib-imagex`.

- So mount the official ISO image – on `/mnt`, for example.  Prepare a file
  for the USB image (it will not fit on a 4 GB stick, so go for an 8 GB image).

  ```
  $ sudo mount -o loop  Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso /mnt 
  $ dd if=/dev/zero of=win10_inst.usb bs=4M count=1900
  ```
- Format the image with FAT32.

  ```
  $ sudo mkdosfs -F 32 ./win10_inst.usb
  ```
- Copy everything into a temporary folder and remove the `install.wim`.

  ```
  $ mkdir win10_inst   
  $ cp -apr /mnt/* ./win10_inst 
  $ chown -R $(id -un):$(id -un) ./win10_inst
  $ chmod u+w win10_inst
  $ chmod u+w win10_inst/sources
  $ rm ./win10_inst/sources/install.wim
  ```
- Now use `wimlib-imagex` to split the `install.wim`.

  ```
  $ wimlib-imagex split /mnt/sources/install.wim  ./win10_inst/sources/install.swm 3800
  ```
- Change the permissions on the newly created `install*.swm`.

  ```
  $ chown $(id -un):$(id -un) install*.swm   
  $ chmod a+rx   install*.swm
  ```
- Umount the ISO image and mount the USB image.

  ```
  $ sudo umount /mnt   
  $ sudo mount -o loop win10_inst.usb /mnt
  ```
- Copy the content of the temporary folder into the USB image.

  ```
  $ sudo cp -apr win10_inst/* /mnt/   
  $ sync   
  $ sudo umount /mnt
  ```

Now you have a valid USB image that will only boot in UEFI mode. 
You can now dd or cat the image onto a physical USB stick the old way
and it will work.

Comment: NOTE: man usb sticks are not exactly 8Gib but 8 commercial GB (8000000000 bytes)
That is why the count is only 1900 ... so the image will fit hopefully any 8Gb USB stick

Comment: You probably don't need the **``./``** in the ``./win10_inst`` commands.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': probably but it surely won't harm

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to install Windows, I just wanted to run the installer so I could get into recovery mode, open a Command Prompt, and then run a program, in my case a Dell firmware update.

In this case you can still follow the above instructions where you copy the files inside the downloaded .iso file onto a FAT32 partition, you just omit the large `install.wim` file.  Obviously you won't be able to install Windows using that USB stick, but you can still boot to recovery mode and run your firmware update .exe files.

You don't need to run syslinux or anything, as UEFI searches FAT32 partitions for bootable files so it finds it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent reliable approach for me has been:

1. On Linux, set up and launch a virtual machine running Windows.
2. Then run Rufus on VW to create the bootable USB: https://rufus.ie/en/
3. Make sure to check the check box: `List USB Hard Drives` on Rufus UI.
4. I had to plug and unplug my USB multiple times before VM and Rufus could detect it.

I have tested it on openSUSE Leap 15.5.

## VM runs Windows

[image: VM screenshot]

## Use VM to run Rufus

[image: Rufus screenshot]