# Changing the boot entries of a Windows ISO using mkisofs to use cdboot_noprompt.efi instead of cdboot.efi

Tags: linux, windows, iso, disk-image, mkisofs

When you boot a Windows 10 ISO, you will get this misleading prompt:
[image]
Why is it misleading? Because this message comes from the Windows ISO itself after you actually already booted from it.
This prompt is a feature that is supposed to prevent you from accidentally booting in your Windows image.

Now I have a very specific use-case in which this prompt makes it impossible for me to automatically create and install a UEFI-based Windows 10 VM.

So I've done some digging and on Windows you can create a Windows ISO without the prompt by specifying a `noprompt` image on the boot entry like so:

```
$setfsboot="C:\01_TEMP\ISO\etfsboot.com"
$sefisys ="C:\01_TEMP\ISO\efisys_noprompt.bin"
Oscdimg -bootdata:2#p0,eb$setfsboot#pEF,e,b$sefisys -u1 
-udfver102 C:\winpe_amd64\media C:\winpe_amd64\winpeamd64.iso
```

**Quick explanation**

`-bootdata:2#p0,eb$setfsboot#pEF,e,b$sefisys`

- `2` means there are 2 boot entries
- `#` separator
- `p0,eb$setfsboot` is the default boot entry (for legacy BIOS boot)
- `#` separator
- `pEF,e,b$sefisys` is the fallback boot entry (for UEFI boot)

[Documentation for OSCdimg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options)

Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing on Linux using mkisofs, which is very tricky because just in order to make a UEFI-bootable Windows ISO, you need the upstream version of `mkisofs` (see [this post by mkey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635839/126773)) (Which can be obtained [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/).) The versions of `mkisofs` that come with Linux distributions apparently lack some features and have ancient bugs in them that never got fixed.

I've tried removing `efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi` and then renaming `efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi` to `efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi` in order to trick the ISO, but that didn't work unfortunately.

At the moment I use this code to extract a boot image from the ISO directly:

```
BOOT_LOAD_SEG="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Media load segment: " | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
BOOT_LOAD_SIZE="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Load Sectors: " | grep -o "[^:]*$" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | head -1)"

EFI_STARTING_SECTOR="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Load LBA: " | grep -o "[^:]*$" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tail -1)"
echo "EFI_STARTING_SECTOR: $EFI_STARTING_SECTOR"

sudo dd if="${WIN10_IMG}" of="${TMP}/efi.dmp" bs=2048 count=1 skip="${EFI_STARTING_SECTOR}"
EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE="$(file "${TMP}/efi.dmp" | grep -oP 'sectors (\d+)' | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
echo "EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE: ${EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE}"

sudo dd if="${WIN10_IMG}" of="${ISO_FILES}/efi/win_efi_boot.img" bs=2048 count="${EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE}" skip="${EFI_STARTING_SECTOR}"
```

In the last command above, the extracted image is placed in the folder containing the files extracted from the ISO.

Then using the `-eltorito-boot "efi/win_efi_boot.img"` flag for `mkisofs`, I tell it to use that for the boot entry.

I have written a script that automatically sets up everything you need in order to get to the point where I am right now.
If you take a look at `STEP 5` in the script you can see my attempt to change the file names, but I think, I may have to change `STEP 4` instead, but I just don't know how.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#You might have to install a few dependencies for schily tools to compile.
#On Fedora this did the trick for me: `sudo dnf install e2fsprogs-devel imake gcc-c++`

############ STEP 1 download Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft ##############
WIN10_IMG="$(pwd)/windows10.iso" 
WIN10_IMG_ARCH="x64"

if [ ! -f "$WIN10_IMG" ]; then # if the windows10.iso has not been downloaded yet
    if [[ "$WIN10_IMG_ARCH" == "x86" ]] || [[ "$WIN10_IMG_ARCH" == "i386" ]] ; then
        echo "Retrieving the x86 Windows 10 iso URL..."
        WINDOWS_10_ISO_URL=$(curl -LsI -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=7e583fea") # This strange looking URL actually redirects to a legit software-download.microsoft.com URL 
    else
        echo "Retrieving the x64 Windows 10 iso URL..."
        WINDOWS_10_ISO_URL=$(curl -LsI -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=3dd1ce66") # This strange looking URL actually redirects to a legit software-download.microsoft.com URL 
    fi

    echo "Download URL: $WINDOWS_10_ISO_URL"
    echo "Making sure the URL comes from a trusted Microsoft domain..."
    if [[ $WINDOWS_10_ISO_URL == https://software-download.microsoft.com/* ]] ; then
        echo "Downloading the Windows 10 installation iso..."
        wget "$WINDOWS_10_ISO_URL" -O "$WIN10_IMG"
    else
        echo "URL validation failed. Please download the Windows 10 iso manually."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
#########################################################################


############## STEP 2 download and build the schily tools ###############

SCHILY_VERSION="2021-06-07"
SCHILY_ARCHIVE="schily-${SCHILY_VERSION}.tar.bz2"
SCHILY_DIR="./schily-tools"

if [ ! -f "${SCHILY_DIR}/mkisofs/OBJ/x86_64-linux-gcc/mkisofs" ]; then # if the mkisofs of Schily Tools has not been built yet
    sudo rm -rf "${SCHILY_DIR}"
    wget "https://altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/schilytools/${SCHILY_ARCHIVE}" -O "${SCHILY_ARCHIVE}"
    tar -xf "${SCHILY_ARCHIVE}"
    rm "${SCHILY_ARCHIVE}"
    mv "schily-${SCHILY_VERSION}" "${SCHILY_DIR}"
    cd "${SCHILY_DIR}"
    ./Gmake.linux
    cd ..
    if [ ! -f "${SCHILY_DIR}/mkisofs/OBJ/x86_64-linux-gcc/mkisofs" ]; then
        echo "Building Schily Tools failed"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
#########################################################################


################# STEP 3 Extract the files from the ISO #################
TMP="./tmp"
ISO_FILES="${TMP}/iso-files"
ISO_MP="${TMP}/iso-mountpoint"
if [ ! -f "${ISO_FILES}/setup.exe" ]; then # If the Windows ISO hasn't been extracted yet
    sudo rm -rf "${TMP}"
    mkdir -p "${ISO_FILES}"
    mkdir -p "${ISO_MP}"
    sudo mount -t udf "${WIN10_IMG}" "${ISO_MP}"
    sudo cp -Rva ${ISO_MP}/* "${ISO_FILES}"
    sudo umount "${ISO_MP}"
fi
#########################################################################


################## STEP 4 Extract the EFI boot image ####################
# Extract boot load segment address and size
BOOT_LOAD_SEG="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Media load segment: " | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
BOOT_LOAD_SIZE="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Load Sectors: " | grep -o "[^:]*$" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | head -1)"

EFI_STARTING_SECTOR="$(dumpet -i "${WIN10_IMG}" | grep "Load LBA: " | grep -o "[^:]*$" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tail -1)"
echo "EFI_STARTING_SECTOR: $EFI_STARTING_SECTOR"

sudo dd if="${WIN10_IMG}" of="${TMP}/efi.dmp" bs=2048 count=1 skip="${EFI_STARTING_SECTOR}"
EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE="$(file "${TMP}/efi.dmp" | grep -oP 'sectors (\d+)' | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
echo "EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE: ${EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE}"

sudo dd if="${WIN10_IMG}" of="${ISO_FILES}/efi/win_efi_boot.img" bs=2048 count="${EFI_BOOT_LOAD_SIZE}" skip="${EFI_STARTING_SECTOR}"
#########################################################################


######## STEP 5 Make changes to the files extracted from the ISO ########
# Make some arbitrary changes to the iso files
#sudo rm -rf "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi"
#sudo mv "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi" "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi"
#sudo rm -rf "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/efisys.bin"
#sudo mv "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/efisys_noprompt.bin" "${ISO_FILES}/efi/microsoft/boot/efisys.bin"
#########################################################################


###### STEP 6 Build a new ISO using the extracted/modified files ########
sudo rm -f "${WIN10_IMG}.tmp.iso"
sudo "${SCHILY_DIR}/mkisofs/OBJ/x86_64-linux-gcc/mkisofs" \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -b boot/etfsboot.com \
  -boot-load-seg "${BOOT_LOAD_SEG}" \
  -boot-load-size "${BOOT_LOAD_SIZE}" \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -eltorito-boot "efi/win_efi_boot.img" \
  -boot-load-size 1 \
  -iso-level 4 \
  -UDF \
  -o "${WIN10_IMG}.tmp.iso" \
  "${ISO_FILES}"
#########################################################################


############ STEP 7 Remove the files exxtracted from the ISO ############
#sudo rm -f "${TMP}"
#########################################################################
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm currently trying the same thing :-)

Comment: I ended up with a hack/workaround sending keystrokes for a few seconds programmatically using `virsh send-key`: https://github.com/T-vK/MobilePassThrough/blob/7102471fa5eb2be16126f02a7445091672c84376/scripts/main/vm.sh#L824

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the iso to efi-boot with no prompt like this:

```
7z x windows.iso -oiso-unpack

mkisofs -b boot/etfsboot.com -no-emul-boot -c BOOT.CAT -iso-level 4 -J -l -D -N -joliet-long -relaxed-filenames -v -V "Custom" -udf -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -eltorito-boot efi/microsoft/boot/efisys_noprompt.bin -no-emul-boot -o install.iso -allow-limited-size iso-unpack
```

Note: this requires mkisofs from schilytools (not packaged for most distros due to licensing issues) or the alternative binary from genisoimage (packaged for most distros). The alternative binary xorriso cannot be used, because it does not support UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared any error messages of where/how what you are attempting is failing.

The method you are doing to mess with the UEFI boot process seems like the long way around for what you say you to want to do.

Most places that do large VM roll outs either use some sort of pre-built and validated template image that is cloned to generate new Win10 instances, or perform an OEM style *Unattended Install* with a Windows PE created `.WIM` file to build the environment and chose the options.

The section you link for OSCdimg, is just one of those tools that are available to licensed hardware manufacturers for new hardware deployment. I bet it performs something similar in function to efibootmgr in linux in addition to recreating the ISO image. Part of its function is to sign the resulting files, I don't see why else MS would have included a public certificate file in that directory which would allow them to do signature verification of their binaries without network access.

**Addendum:** Did some reading on the EFI spec(you should too). Have you thought to just tell mkisofs to use
`-eltorito-boot efi\microsoft\boot\cdboot_noprompt.efi`
I'm not positive which way around uefi wants it directory deliminators since according to the spec it is supposed to support FAT and looking at the ISO in an editor I have, there is a UDF partition which is where I got that path.

I got some good insight from:
https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/