# How to create a Windows 10 ISO from the bash prompt

Tags: boot, windows, iso

I'm trying to generate a custom bootable Windows 10 ISO using the command prompt (it needs to be automatable so GUI won't work). I've been trying to use `mkisofs` but not sure which options are needed for bootable Windows 10. I've tried from the directory containing the Windows files:

```
mkisofs -no-emul-boot -b boot/etfsboot.com -boot-load-seg 0x07C0 -boot-load-size 8 -udf -joliet-long -D -N -relaxed-filenames -allow-limited-size -l -J -r -iso-level 3 -o win1809v2auto.iso .
```

But the result won't start in VMware Workstation. Does anyone know what the correct flags are that I need?

Similar (what got me this far):

[How to create bootable Windows 8 iso image in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283446/how-to-create-bootable-windows-8-iso-image-in-linux?rq=1)

[How to Create Bootable Windows 10 image in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312488/how-to-create-bootable-windows-10-image-in-debian?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In my experience, the overall process seems to be quite error prone. Are you positively sure you need an ISO? Would a bootable virtual drive be sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Hermann but I'm actually only using VMware to test. I actually have a handy little USB HDD/SSD adapter that you can fill with ISOs and then it presents them as virtual CDs. So that's ultimately where it needs to end up.

Comment: what device are you referring to?

Comment: @jsotola It's an iodd, I think a 2531.